# Как добавить view по условию

Tags: java, классы

Есть активити

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {

    private Level2 view;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.game_layout);

       RelativeLayout layout = 
               (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.game_relativelayuot);
                view = new Level2(this, getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE), layout); 
                layout.addView(view, 0);
```

и есть view

```
public class Level2 extends View {
```

Проблема в том что классов `level` несколько (`level1, level2, level3` и далее...)

Как указать их по условию? К примеру если `1 = 1` то отображать `level3`

Заработало вот так

```
   RelativeLayout layout = 
           (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.game_relativelayuot);

   List<View> levels = new ArrayList<>();
   levels.add(new Level1(this, getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE), layout));
   levels.add(new Level2(this, getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE), layout));
   levels.add(new Level3(this, getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE), layout));
   int ggr = 1;
   if(1==1){ggr = 1;};
   if(1==2){ggr = 2;};
   if(1==3){ggr = 3;};
   layout.addView(levels.get(ggr), 0);
```

Comment: оформите свое решение в виде ответа, а не пишите его в вопрос. Так же вы можете принять свое же решение, как верное.

Comment: все понял     ......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос в том, насколько кардинальны отличия в методах. Если к методам уровня не нужно обращаться, то засунуть в один список по суперклассу:

```
List<View> levels = new ArrayList<>();
levels.add(new Level1(this, getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE), layout));
levels.add(new Level2(this, getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE), layout));
levels.add(new Level3(this, getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE), layout));

layout.addView(levels.get(n), 0);
```

Или как вариант создать единый интерфейс и провернуть схожий оборот.

Comment: здравствуйте @Riĥard Brugekĥaim а как это будет выглядеть? к примеру если при запуске этого класса переменная level_id = 3 то мне надо запустить соответственно level3 ? и где именно мне вписать этот код?

Comment: @РоманЗыков Как я уже сказал - вопрос в том, различаются ли у разных уровней методы, к которым вы обращаетесь. Если же такой необходимости нет, то .... сейчас обновлю свой ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Заработало вот так:

```
   RelativeLayout layout = 
           (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.game_relativelayuot);

   List<View> levels = new ArrayList<>();
   levels.add(new Level1(this, getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE), layout));
   levels.add(new Level2(this, getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE), layout));
   levels.add(new Level3(this, getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE), layout));
   int ggr = 1;
   if(1==1){ggr = 1;};
   if(1==2){ggr = 2;};
   if(1==3){ggr = 3;};
   layout.addView(levels.get(ggr), 0);
```